# converting every letter in a string to uppercase or lowercase and vice versa in php

Tags: converters

i'm having a problem. Can you help me know how to convert every letter in a string to uppercase/ lowercase and vice versa. The output is not like what as I expected. Btw this is in PHP.

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
            if(($string[$i]) =='/[^A-Z]/'){
                str_replace('a','A',$string[$i]);
                echo $string;

    }
    else {
                strtolower($string[$i]);
                echo $string;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctype_upper() will check if the $i-th string is uppercase. Additionally, in your code, `strtolower($string[$i])` must then be assigned to `$string[$i]`. Here is a working example:

```
<?php

$string = "lowers UPPERS";

for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
    if(ctype_upper($string[$i])){
        $string[$i] = strtolower($string[$i]);
    }
    else {
        $string[$i] = strtoupper($string[$i]);
    }
}

echo $string;

?>
```